# Use Xcode debugger to determine the type of objects stored in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, lldb

How do you use Xcode debugger (lldb or gdb) to determine the type of objects that's stored in an NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this in lldb is to use a combination of lldb's data formatters - which include one that presents NSArray objects as "real" arrays - and the "dynamic type" facility in `expr` - which pulls out the real, as opposed to declared, types of objects.  So for instance:

```
(lldb) expr -T -d run-target -- *array1
(NSArray) $2 = {
      (__NSCFConstantString *) [0] = 0x0000000100002590 @"array1 object1"
      (__NSCFConstantString *) [1] = 0x00000001000025b0 @"array1 object2"
      (__NSCFConstantString *) [2] = 0x00000001000025d0 @"array1 object3"
}
```

The `-T` option just turned on type printing.  The NSArray "synthetic child provider" is presenting the array as an indexed array of objects.  That works by default, I didn't have to do anything to turn that on.  And the dynamic type option `-d` is decoding the real type of each object.  Note, you can make finding the dynamic type the default in lldb by doing:

```
(lldb) set set target.prefer-dynamic-value run-target
```

This array seems to be full of __NSCFConstantStrings, which is apparently the backing type for constant NSStrings.

Answer (score 5):

Both gdb and lldb support calling methods on objects in memory, and you can print an object with `po`. To get a list of the values of some property for all the objects in an `NSArray`, use `valueForKey:`. The property you seem to be interested in is `class`.

Putting that all together:

```
po [theArray valueForKey:@"class"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4.6 or later, the Xcode UI will show that information for you